# Consulta a dos tablas sin repertir los registross

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo dos tablas pedidos y productos pedidos

ejemplo tabla pedido

```
idpedido , sucursal diseñador
```

tabala prodocuto pedido

```
idproductopedido,idPedido,producto,medical
```

¿como puedo traerme solo los pedidos y saber si en la tabala productopedido el pedido tiene un producto que es medical?

si tengo 10 pedidos  y  17 productospedidos al hacer un left join o un inner join se repiten me arroja 27 **solo necesito los pedidos pero saber si en esos pedidos hay un producto que es medical**

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es realizar una subconsulta para obtener si existe un producto medical

ejemplo:

```
Select idpedido , sucursal diseñador,(select count(medical) from prodocutopedido WHERE prodocutopedido.idPedido=Pedido..idPedido and medical) as medical FROM Pedido
```

Comment: lo voy a revisar gracias

Comment: me  marca error Select id_pedido , id_sucursal,id_diseniador,(select count(medical) from productos_pedidos WHERE productos_pedidos.id_pedido=pedidos.id_pedido and medical) as medical FROM pedidos           Reference 'medical' not supported (forward reference in item list)